# Underline under Line Descenent

Tags: android, underline

I want to draw a line under line descent in SpannableStringBuilder.

If I use UnderlineSpan, it draws the line on baseline:

```
SpannableStringBuilder sample = new SpannableStringBuilder("This is Graphical Test)";
sample.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, sample.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Here's the result:

[image]

As you can see underline is drawn on baseline. If I want to underline is drawn under text descent line.

This is what I want:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: use custom `ReplacementSpan`

Comment: Could you write a sample please?

Comment: no, its your job to implement the abstract methods

Comment: If I could, I wouldn't ask. Thanks anyway

Comment: so what abstract method do you have problems with?

Comment: I wanna apply underline for peace of text, and it has getSize method which I dont't know what is it.

Comment: `"Returns the width of the span"` so you have to return your custom span width in pixels - the `Paint` parameter can be helpful  here